# Understanding the overflow property

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to create a `div` that contains a list of floated images. Because of the amount of them, they break the container. I want the container to scroll horizontally when they do. At the moment, it just breaks, stacking them vertically:

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/YUhF9/1/

CSS

```
.slideshow-container-row-3 {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 1025px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

    .img {
    width: 160px;
    background-color: orange;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.img:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="slideshow-container-row-3">
    <div class="img">.</div>
    <div class="img">.</div>
    <div class="img">.</div>
     <div class="img">.</div>
    <div class="img">.</div>
    <div class="img">.</div>
    <div class="img">.</div>
    <div class="img">.</div>
    <div class="img">.</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `float`, instead make them `display: inline-block;` and use `white-space: nowrap;` on the wrapper element to prevent the wrapping.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YUhF9/4/)

```
.slideshow-container-row-3 {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 1025px;
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.img {
    width: 160px;
    background-color: orange;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;

    /* Use these as well */
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

> **Important Note:** Make sure you use `white-space: normal;` for the child elements i.e `.img` else they will inherit the parent property. Also use `vertical-align: top;` to the `.img` as `inline-block` are aligned to the `baseline` by default.

Comment: Also, `white-space:normal` doesn't seem to change anything: http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/YUhF9/7/

Comment: @tmyie it doesn't apply to `float`, also, if you won't use `white-space: normal` than see what happens http://jsfiddle.net/YUhF9/8/ and using it renders what... http://jsfiddle.net/YUhF9/9/

Comment: How come this is still not wrapping the text? I've copied and pasted your CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/YUhF9/11/

Comment: @tmyie you have a string without space so for that you need to use `word-wrap: break-word;` http://jsfiddle.net/YUhF9/12/

Answer (score 1):

I though it be best to declare a container within a container

**HTML Section**

```
<div class="less_container">
    <div class="slideshow-container-row-3">
        <div class="img">.</div>
        <div class="img">.</div>
        <div class="img">.</div>
        <div class="img">.</div>
        <div class="img">.</div>
        <div class="img">.</div>
        <div class="img">.</div>
        <div class="img">.</div>
        <div class="img">.</div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS edition**

```
.less_container{
    height: 250px;
    width: 1025px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.slideshow-container-row-3 {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 1540px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
    width: 160px;
    background-color: orange;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.img:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```